# optimise data transfer speed from an external USB 3.0 docking?

Tags: external-hdd, usb-drive

What can I do to optimise the data transfer speed from an external USB 3.0 docking? I have two HDDs inserted into the docking device, and I have it connected via only USB 3.0 on my laptop (blue colored one). I get rsync speeds of 50MB/s but I am not sure if this is the maximum speed I can get and how I could tweak it to optimal speed.

Comment: Experiment using different USB ports.  Not all ports/controllers are equal and you might be surprised at the different speeds between two ports.

Comment: Can you find your docking in this list: `sudo lsusb -v | grep bcdUSB -C5`? Please add the output for your docking to the question.

Comment: Are your drives SSD?

Comment: Your speed are limited to your HDD speed , unless you're running on SSD drives , but that's not fast enough as well

Comment: Dual-drive docks can be slow -- 50 MB/s is fine if you're copying from one docked drive to the other.

Comment: @izx I am copying the data from a docked drive to a hybrid SSD/HDD drive inside the laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You should remember that the data is transferred to the destination,
>   only as fast it is being read off the source.
>
> USB 2.0 has a maximum theoretical speed limit of 60 MB/s. Actually, it
>   is only today, 8 years after the launch of USB 2, that USB 2 devices
>   are able to fully exploit this speed.  Most of the USB 2 devices today
>   max out at 30-35 MB/s. The reason for this, the read-write speeds of
>   devices bottlenecks the transfer process.
>
> Of course USB 3.0 isn't all about speed. The new bus specification is
>   also intended to accommodate the next generation of power hungry
>   devices, gadgets and drives.
>
> So for USB 3, don't expect speeds of 400 MB/s plus; even though the
>   data could be transferred at that rate, it cannot be read off the
>   source HDD or written to the external drive at the same rate. Now if
>   you were to hook up a superfast SSD to the dock, & also had a similar
>   speed SSD in your system, then the transfer process would be
>   definitely faster, since both drives could read & write lighteningly
>   fast. So it is more likely that the transfers you are doing are
>   bottlenecked by the storage drives, in particularl, their sequential
>   read/write speeds; not due to the fault of USB 3.

<sup>Source: [tomshardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/282887-28-transfer-speed-slow)</sup>